# How to determine u(t+1) - u(t-1) as even, odd or neither?

Tags: signal, system

x(t) = u(t+1) - u(t-1) is given.

How do we determine if it is an even or odd signal or neither? Do we plot it out or do we use the condition and convert it.

and also, is it even or odd?

Comment: Explain yourself what is an odd or even waveform, draw the signal and there you go.

Answer (score 2):

The technique to determine if it is even or odd (or neither) can be either graphical or analytical, depending on what is simpler to do. That from a practical point of view.

If you are a student and you are required to prove your conclusions, the acceptable way depends on which rules are set by your instructor.

Anyway, the analitical conditions to be satisfied are:

$$
  x(t) \mathrm{~is~even} \qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad \forall t \qquad x(-t) = x(t)
$$

$$
  x(t) \mathrm{~is~odd} \qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad \forall t \qquad x(-t) = -x(t)
$$

From a graphical POV the first condition means that the graph of \$x(t)\$ is symmetrical about the vertical axis, whereas the second condition means that the graph is symmetrical about the origin.

Since this seems some sort of homework question, I won't give you the full solution (this is the policy of this site wrt. homework questions).